# Where is Emulator settings is Android Studio 1.5.1?

Tags: pc-studio

I take on-line course https://class.coursera.org/androidpart1-011/ and have many troubles with setup.

IDE (on Linux host) uses `/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator` which after some checks run `emulator64-x86` which doesn't work! 32-bit version work great.

Also PulseAudio code in Emulator purely written and leads to 100% CPU load.

Also official docs suggest add `-qemu -enable-kvm` options.

So I need a way to change path to `emulator` executable and/or pass additional options:

```
-force-32bit -noaudio -qemu -enable-kvm
```

Intellij have special tab for this settings: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-android-application.html

But I can't see Emulator tub in Android Studio 1.5.1:

[image]

Where is Emulator settings is Android Studio 1.5.1 (shame Google for frustrating GUI)?

**PS** Can any high score user add `android-studio` tag to question?

Comment: This site is for *users* of Android, which means that questions about development/programming are off-topic here (see the [What topics can I ask about here?](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)). Development questions are on-topic on our sister site [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). You might also wish to consult [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) for a fitting place to your question. BTW: That's the reason why there's no `android-studio` tag here :)

Comment: @lzzy Thanks for feedback. I will follow your suggestion in future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm... I need to downgrade to version 1.4:

- http://tools.android.com/download/studio/stable

or wait for fix to:

- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195031
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33909062/no-emulator-tab-in-edit-configurations-in-android-studio